# python Looping through user entires

Tags: python, variables, loops, input

I need help with python script coding as I am new with python.
A simple example is that I want to show an input for the user asking him how many folders he wants to create. Then showing input boxes for each folder name.

After the user completes the process I want python to check if the folders exist. If not it will start creating each folder with the name that the user entered and create an empty text file inside it. With the limitation for this process to 25 folders at max.

Output example

```
System : How many Folders you want to create ? (Max 25)
User   : 3
System : Folder 1 Name ?
User   : 1
System : Folder 2 Name ?
User   : 2
System : Folder 3 Name ?
User   : 3
```

Any help ??

Comment: Which part you cannot figure out?

Answer (score 1):

There are several assumptions that I'm making when I read your question:

- The user interacts via a command-line, i.e. not a proper GUI
- If the number of directories to be created is invalid (i.e. not a proper number or is greater than 25), then the program will print some error message
- If some of the folder name inputted already exists, the program will simply skip creating that folder and continue with the rest of the folder name inputs

```py
import os

# Setting up variables
currentDirectory = "./"
numDirs = 0
dirNames = []

# Populating user input
try:
    numDirs = int(raw_input("How many Folders you want to create ? (Max 25)\n"))
except:
    print "Number of directories must be a number"

if (numDirs > 25):
    print "Too many directories to create!"
else:
    for i in range(numDirs):
        dirNames.append(raw_input( "Folder %d Name ?\n" % (i+1) ))

# Creating the named directories
for name in dirNames:
    fullPath = currentDirectory + name
    if not os.path.isdir( fullPath ):
        # Directory name is legitimate and not already existent
        os.mkdir( fullPath )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code , It was useful , but when it tried to restrict the folders name also to be a number , an error has been shown .

Comment: I think the use of `raw_input` also assumes Python 2.X (I did not see this noted anywhere in the original post).